# A better way to say "... that will be fought"

Tags: phrasing

I'm searching a shorter way to say "Something that will be fought". I'm actually creating an app and I'd need it as a title for a field. So it needs to be short and relevant, but I can't find another way to say it. Thank you.

EDIT : It's a living thing that will be fought, like a person.

EDIT 2 : To be clear, the user will choose a monster to fight. So I'd like to write "Monster that will be fought" in a shorter way, but not just "Opponent", as it's too vague. I hope I'll be understood now, sorry.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for. For example, a 'battle' is something that will be fought (or a war), is that what you mean?  What are some examples of items that will go in this field?

Comment: No, sorry for my bad explanation. I meant something living, like a person.

Comment: adversary? foe?

Comment: What, you mean like an **opponent**?

Comment: Yes, exactly, an opponent!

Edit : But in this context, saying "Opponent something" seems really weird, even if it's correct. I'd like something that the user won't focus on

Comment: Okay, I'll make that into an answer so that the question is no longer on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas (some stolen from other answers I will admit):

Imply something attacking you or against you in some way, or with negative (evil alignment) connotations:

- Adversary
- Antagonist
- Assailant
- Enemy
- Challenger

Something neutral or equal to you:

- Opponent
- Rival
- Target

Something innocent that you are attacking mercilessly:

- Victim

Answer (score 0):

An opponent is someone (not something) to be fought.

[opponent](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=opponent%20meaning)
əˈpəʊnənt/
noun
someone who competes with or opposes another in a contest, game, or argument.

Also adversary, foe as suggested by Ricky.

Comment: I'll quote myself, as I edited my comment : In this context, saying "Opponent something" seems really weird, even if it's correct. I'd like something that the user won't focus on

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Opponent something". Where is anything like that mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is really bad. I'll edit it with more explanations. Again, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **nemesis**.

> : an opponent or enemy that is very difficult to defeat.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis)